# Laravel 5.4 : Get logged in user id inside __construct()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to access `Auth::user()->id;` inside constructor but it always return the error **Trying to get property of non-object**. I study in the laravel documentation that Session is not accessible inside constructor and also search on SO for this. I need logged in user id inside constructor because I have to fetch data from database and make it available for all its method. My current code is :

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $induction_status = TrainingStatusRecord::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('training','=','induction')->get();
    View::share('ind_status',$induction_status);
}
```

Is there any way (easy way) to get logged in user id inside constructor.

I will appreciate any help.

Thank You

Comment: In which Class  u want to do that? This is important to know... when gets it instanciated?

Comment: Did  you have `id` as your primary key within your table? Please also check what does `Auth::user()` prints out

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia !!! `Auth::user()` inside constructor nothing prints, Just showing blank page... I use `echo '<pre>';print_r(Auth::user());exit;` inside constructor

Comment: Still you looking for solution ? I have a different method to do that

Comment: Yes @recoverymen :)  I am just thinking to do it with Helper if I dont found any solution to get logged in user id inside constructor. And I am looking forward to see your solution.... :)

Comment: yes dear its a good idea no need to go to helper ever you worked with AppServiceProvider ?

Comment: Actually I am very new to Laravel so, its easy to me....

Comment: @recoverymen I am very curious to see your solution....

Comment: wait i am answering your question

Comment: Oh thats great @recoverymen ! keep going

Comment: It seems you don't have successfully logged in within system

Comment: Dear @NarendrasinghSisodia !!! I am logged in successfully and everything is working fine except this issue.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To share a variable in view **AppServiceProvider** is a good approach

Go to **App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**

**Include facade on top of the page**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\TrainingStatusRecord;
```

and paste below code in **boot** method

```
view()->composer('*', function($view){
        if(Auth::user()){
            $induction_status = TrainingStatusRecord::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('training','=','induction')->get();
            View::share('induction_status',$induction_status);
        }
    });
```

Now you will be able to get your variable `$induction_status` in your app.

**Reference** https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers#the-boot-method

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi @recoverymen... Its working fine. Could you please let me know if I make a function inside **Bootstrap\app.php** will work same as you make it inside **App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php** is there any major difference?

Comment: i think Bootstrap\app.php returns the application instance. sorry i am not sure about it.

Comment: Well Thank you @recoverymen! +1 Happy Coding :)

Comment: Nice explanation @bluemoon, +1 for this

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` was indeed my first guess. This would work mostly but with an exception to access `Session` data.

So If you try to access `Session` data within **boot** method of **AppServiceProvider** you will get `null`. So to do this so it works perfectly good in any case `Middleware` is a good option. You can write this logic of sharing a variable to all your desired views. Just create a `middleware` and include that in your `route` or `routegroup` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $induction_status = TrainingStatusRecord::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('training','=','induction')->get();
    }
    View::share('induction_status',$induction_status);
}
```