# How to make public accessible controller in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel

I am not sure if my question is clear. I have a query in my controller which counts messages that are not yet been read. I inserted in one of the controller of a specific page. The result is fine when I refreshed the page but when I click to another page which means another route, it throws an error which says the variable is not declared (I notice because I inserted it only in one specific controller).
The result should be notified in the header of my page view (My header is visible in all pages of my site). The problem is How can I make a single call so that the query will be applied in all pages. Bellow is the UI.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIKe2.png)

My Controller where I inserted the query

```
class InvPaginateController extends Controller
{
    public function inv_pagination()
    {
        $it_equipments = DB::table('it_equipments')->paginate(7);
        $areas = Areas::all(['id','area_name']);
        $dept_offs = DeptOffice::all(['id','dept_name']);
        $messages = DB::table('messages')->where('status','=', 0)->count();
        $messbody = DB::table('messages')->where('status','=', 0)->paginate(5);
        return view('it_equipments.inv_pagination', compact('it_equipments'), compact('areas','dept_offs','messages','messbody'));
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a middleware for it.

Comment: please click the link to view the image sirs.

Comment: View below link answered by me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133361/laravel-5-4-get-logged-in-user-id-inside-construct/43134097#43134097

Comment: Simply, Inject InvPaginateController object in view through template @inject() method and call a method which only return the counter, define another method in this controller and only return counter from it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare custom controller

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct() 
    {
        $it_equipments = DB::table('it_equipments')->paginate(7);
    $areas = Areas::all(['id','area_name']);
    $dept_offs = DeptOffice::all(['id','dept_name']);
    $messages = DB::table('messages')->where('status','=', 0)->count();
    $messbody = DB::table('messages')->where('status','=', 0)->paginate(5);
    View::share(compact('areas','dept_offs','messages','messbody'));
    }
}
```

now every controller extended as BaseController will share this variables

Comment: do i need to make route of this controller?

Comment: how can i call this custom controller? Do i need to make route and how should it be?

Comment: no, you need to make your controller class(which you need to share this variables) extended from   BaseController

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this
In your `AppServiceProvider`

```
 view()->composer('layouts.default', function($view){
           $it_equipments = DB::table('it_equipments')->paginate(7);
           $areas = Areas::all(['id','area_name']);
           $dept_offs = DeptOffice::all(['id','dept_name']);
           $messages = DB::table('messages')->where('status','=', 0)->count();
           $messbody = DB::table('messages')->where('status','=', 0)->paginate(5);
           $view->with(compact('it_equipments','areas','dept_offs','messages','messbody'));
       });
```

`layouts.default` - Your default layout your are using. 
All the variable you passed will available in the views created using the `default.blade.php` inside the `layouts` folder

Comment: do you mean home.blade.php?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I already got it working. I placed it inside boot function in AppServiceProvider and replaced layouts.default with adminlte::layouts.app