# create a session that is accessible on all methods of the controller

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am working on an e-commerce project in laravel and the guest can add items to his cart before logging in and for that I am planning to use a session which will help be keep track of all items for this customer..

the project has many views but I am using same controller for displaying all of them so I was trying to find someway in which I can create a session ( I tried in the constructor but then it is not working as it is getting re-created )

my constructor code

```
public function __construct()
    {
$pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $finalCode = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, 12)), 0, 12);
            session(['UserIdentity' => $finalCode]);
        $abc = session('UserIdentity');
        if(!(isset($abc)))
        {
            // Auto generated Code
            $pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $finalCode = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, 12)), 0, 12);
            session(['UserIdentity' => $finalCode]);

            $finalsession = session('UserIdentity');
            dd($finalsession);
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me a workaround where I can make this work or any other solution is also welcome.

Thanking you in anticipation..

Comment: According to your criteria I prefer to use `cookie` instead of `session`

Comment: The guest does not have a fix entry point like he can do ww.abc.com or ww.abc.com/products .. so I will have to create it whenever he enters

Comment: @DhavalChheda please see my answer here might be it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133361/laravel-5-4-get-logged-in-user-id-inside-construct/43134097#43134097

Comment: Thanks for sharing that but my issue is that I need to create a random number first and that will be associated with the guest and that I need to be able to access from all views .. The issue with View Composer will be that it will recreate the variable every time a view is called.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a `middleware` on guest routes and then you can use sessions as per your application requirements.

From Laravel 5.3 and onwards, sessions are not accessible within constructors. As all routes use `web` middleware which enables sessions feature for your application. which is executed after the constructor.