# How to pass a variable without Controller in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, view

I have a application with extends a view with name "notification". How you can see in the picture.

[image]

That fragment is just a list, don't extends anything, How I pass a variable to that list? Something fixed. Any suggestion?

```
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="livicon" data-name="bell" data-loop="true" data-color="#e9573f"
           data-hovercolor="#e9573f" data-size="28"></i>
        <span class="label label-warning">7</span>
    </a>
    <ul class=" notifications dropdown-menu drop_notify">
        <li class="dropdown-title">Você tem novas notificações</li>
        <li>
            <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
            <ul class="menu">
              @foreach($notificacao as $value)


                <li>
                    <i class="livicon default" data-n="asterisk" data-s="20" data-c="white"
                       data-hc="white"></i>
                    <a href="http://tycoontech.com.br/novoerp/admin/mlb">Você tem novas perguntas</a>
                    <small class="pull-right">
                        <span class="livicon paddingright_10" data-n="timer" data-s="10"></span>
                        {{$value->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
                    </small>
                </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="footer">
            <a href="#">View all</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Here view my answer hope it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133361/laravel-5-4-get-logged-in-user-id-inside-construct/43134097#43134097

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for help @bluemoon