# How to use a php variable in all blades files in Laravel-5.4?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

How can i use a variable in all blades page ?

**Controller**

```
public function index1(){

$article='var-1';
return view('index',compact('article');

}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
{{ $article }}
```

> **Result of *index.blade.php***
>
> ```
> var-1
> ```

**index2.blade.php**

```
{{ $article }}
```

> **Result of *index2.blade.php***
>
> ```
> Not Found
> ```

It is my problem to find out a way to use one variable and use that in my all *.blade.php files.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Here i have simple answer . have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133361/laravel-5-4-get-logged-in-user-id-inside-construct/43134097#43134097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Composer and pass the data on the main view.

Example:

```
class MyComposer
{ 
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $article='var-1';    
        $view->with(['article' => article]);
    }
}
```

and call the class in your `AppServiceProvider` class inside the `boot()` function like this:

```
view()->composer('layouts.app', MyComposer::class);
```

`layouts.app` is the main view which is included on your views

If you need more info see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers)

Comment: He wants to share same variable in all views not showing the variable each time the same view is rendering

Comment: I prefer to keep my code clean and not just throw code inside `boot()` everytime I need a new variable.

Comment: Then generate a separate service provider to house them )) composer view is not the answer you could read the official documents they mention that

Comment: Is it efficient to make db calls on Providers?

Answer (score 1):

You can [Pass data to all views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views) easily.
Just add the following in your `AppServiceProvider.php` inside the `boot()` method:

```
 View::share('key', 'value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application using the view facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's `boot` method. You are free to add them to the `AppServiceProvider` or generate a separate service provider to house them:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    View::share('key', 'value');
}

/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```